# html validation error while using input type= hidden

Tags: html, validation, input

I keep getting an error message when trying to validate my coding for this form. Could someone run their eyes over it and see if you can pick up on something I haven't.

The error is coming from this line in my coding:

```
<?php if ($ContactID != '') { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="ContactID" value="<?php echo $ContactID ?>"/>
<?php } ?>
```

Actual coding:

```
<!-- Form-->
<form name="editcontact" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"> 
<table border="1" cellpadding="2">
<caption>Edit Contact</caption>

<!--ID Input-->

<?php if ($ContactID != '') { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="ContactID" value="<?php echo $ContactID ?>"/>
<?php } ?>



<!--Name Input-->
<tr>
<td><label for="Name">Name</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo $Name ?>" size="30" maxlength="50" tabindex="1"/>
</td>
</tr>


</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

`input` isn't a valid child of the `table` element. Your provided code will render:

```
<table>
    <input type="hidden" ... >
    ...
</table>
```

You should either wrap this hidden input field within a `td` or `th` element, or move it outside of the table completely:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" ... >
            </td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Or:

```
<input type="hidden" ... >
<table>
    ...
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried putting the hidden element inside <tr><td> however if I do that then I get heaps of other validation errors. e.g. "character "<" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data in all coding that includes this: <input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo $Name ?>" />

Comment: so now I don't really know what is actually wrong with my coding but I can not get it to validate